# Agenda JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

Tengo problemas para realizar lo que me están pidiendo, en cuanto a crear una agenda, me piden que realice una página donde existe un botón enviar el que hará que los primeros datos que el recibe se conviertan en el usuario y contraseña para acceder a la siguiente parte de mi agenda, lo que pasa que en cuanto yo intento realizar esto sólo logro hacer algo que se esta sustituyendo constantemente, no se como crear esta acción de que la primera vez se guarde el usuario y clave, se limpien las casillas y luego tenga que poner los datos de mi primer ingreso para poder acceder de lo contrario me tiene que salir un mensaje de usuario o claves no válidos. También me piden otras validaciones, pero lo más importante que quiero aprender es lo de el registro que no se sustituya con los nuevos valores que yo ponga, como última cosa también debe redireccionar a la página del formulario cuando los datos de inicio sean correctos. (esta función no me la ha explicado mi maestro así que pido ayuda, disculpen si es muy insensato de mi parte pero no tengo noción de como hacerlo).

Acá dejare algo de código que estaba pensando como hacerlo.

También dejaré algunas imágenes del enunciado que me proporcionaron por si acaso no me he explicado bien.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí].[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Java Script**

```
function enviar()
{

    let nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
    let clave=document.getElementById("clave").value;


    if(nombre.length < 1 || clave.length < 1)
        alert("Complete correctamente los campos");
    else{

        alert("Usuario Registrado");
        document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
        document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
        var rnombre=nombre;
        var rclave=clave;
    }
    if(nombre!=rnombre || clave!=rclave){
        alert("nombre de usuario o clave incorrecta");
    }
}
```

Comment: El valor del nombre de usuario y contraseña te piden que las almacenes solo en variables?

Comment: Me pide nada mas almacenarla el enunciado no es explicito en eso, solamente que se almacene y luego que quede como un registro temporal. para iniciar sesión con los datos que se pusieron la primera vez en los inputs.

Comment: Si es almacenamiento temporal se me ocurre utilizar _Cookies_  , pero también está la opción que he visto que estás haciendo y es almacenar el valor de los campos en variables y dejar los campos sin valor. Y con las variables después comparar el nuevo aceso.

Comment: algo así estaba tratando de hacer otra idea también es crear un botón extra que este haga la acción de registrar y con el que ya tengo solamente comparar los valores y tratar de mandar los datos a una variable global para poder usarlo con la función del botón (enviar) pero no se como sacar los datos de esta manera que se me ocurre.

Comment: Creo que entonce las variables de el nombre de usuario y contraseña, deberías declararlas afuera de la función y así cuando le des al boton de enviar se guardan fuera de la función y podrías acceder desde la función registrar que se encargaría de comparar los datos guardados antes y los actuales de los campos.(no sé si me he explicado bien, si no has entendido algo comentalo he intentare decirlo de una forma menos compleja)

Comment: bueno voy a probar. y si pudieras me gustaría que me dieras un ejemplo para entender algo mejor.

Comment: let nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
let clave=document.getElementById("clave").value;
function registro(){
 if(nombre.length < 1 || clave.length < 1)
  alert("Complete correctamente los campos");
 else{
  alert("Usuario Registrado");
  document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
     document.getElementById("nombre").value = "";
     var rnombre=nombre;
     var rclave=clave; // Este nose como usarlo en la validación de abajo
 }
}
function enviar(){
 if(nombre!=rnombre || clave!=rclave){
 alert("nombre de usurio o clave incorrecta");
 }
}

Comment: Te faltó el HTML :C

Answer (score 0):

- Con 2 botones (enviar y registrar):

Fuera de las funciones en el archivo **JavaScript**:

```
var nombre_usuario = "";
var clave_contrasenya = "";
var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
var clave=document.getElementById("clave").value;
```

Función registro:

```
function registro(){
 if(nombre.length < 1 || clave.length < 1){
    alert("Complete correctamente los campos");
  }else{
    alert("Usuario Registrado");
    nombre_usuario = nombre;
    clave_contrasenya = clave;
    nombre="";
    clave="";
  }
}
```

Función enviar:

```
    function enviar(){

    if(nombre!=nombre_usuario || clave!=clave_contrasenya){
        alert("nombre de usuario o clave incorrecta");
    }else{
        window.location="pagina.html"; //redirecciona la página actual a hacia la página que le indiques
    }  
}
```

- Con coockies:

Función enviar:

```
function enviar(){
  var nombre=document.getElementById("nombre").value;
  var clave=document.getElementById("clave").value;
  if((getCookie("nombre")==null || getCookie("nombre")=="") || (getCookie("contrasenya")==null||getCookie("contrasenya")=="")){
    if(getCookie("nombre").length < 1 || getCookie("contrasenya").length < 1{
       alert("Complete correctamente los campos");
    }else{
       alert("Usuario Registrado");
       document.cookie = "nombre = "+nombre;
       document.cookie = "contrasenya = "+clave;
       nombre="";
       clave="";
    }
  }else if(nombre!=getCookie("nombre") || clave!=getCookie("contrasenya")){
          alert("nombre de usuario o clave incorrecta");
        }else{
            window.location="pagina.html"; //redirecciona la página actual a hacia la página que le indiques
        }

    }
}
```

Si quieres elimiar la cookie debes añadir:

```
document.cookie = "nombre=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC";
```

Comment: amigo lo intente implementar y el problema que me estaba tratando de evitar es el mismo con el que esta este, no reconoce los datos de las variables globales en las funciones y da los problemas de variables no declaradas, ahi esta el dato que no se como realizarlo. :/

Comment: Variables no declaradas? Prueba a hacer var nombre_usuario = "";
var clave_contrasenya = "";

Comment: si osea que dentro de la propia función, al abrir la herramienta de desarrollado y ver los problemas de la pagina en la parte de las validaciones con el if, sale el mensaje que variable is not defined.

Comment: @JaimepaOK acabo de añadir el código con cookies a ver si te sirve.